# connect docker postgres from outside (DBeaver)

Tags: postgresql, docker, airflow, dbeaver

I am using Airflow through Docker-compose. The same docker-compose.yml has an image of Postgres as well. The config looks like below -

```
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
```

This works fine for Airflow and I am also able to access the DAG on the UI.

But I want to access the dockerized Postgres instance from an outside SQL client application like **Dbeaver**. But I am not able to do that.

[image: IP Address]

[image: Postgres Setting]

Can someone please help me to resolve this?

Note: I already have a separate Postgres instance running on my local.

Comment: Maybe try localhost instead of 172.x

Comment: localhost is not working too.

Comment: Are you not able to connect on 0.0.0.0:5432 ? If ports are conflicting you can map any other port to 5432 from `ports` in `postgres` service.

Comment: I have this problem too. In addition, I can not add ports `5432:5432`  to `yaml` file as you did. it returns an error that `this address is already in use` but I don't have any other thing that using this port.

Answer (score 12):

You should put 'localhost' instead of '172.25.0.2' and ensure there is no port '5432' already used in your system by using `lsof -i:5432 | grep 'LISTEN'`.

I prefer to use another port. see screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 6):

After trying several times, as @Jashwant mentioned, this port(`5432`) was occupied. Note that it is possible that this port not be shown in `lsof -i -P` command.

So I used another port and instead of `5432:5432`, I used `6543:5432` and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For windows, in `docker-compose.yml` the `-ports:` should be present.

For Linux, you can find the port number using `docker inspect <image-id>`, however for windows and dbeaver, the `localhost` is what is working.

#### Minimal `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "54320:5432"
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

Also, the dbeaver connection - profile :

[image: dbeaver connection]